# Find repeated numbers in certain array positions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

[image]

I am trying to find **repeated values in a multi-dimensional array, based on positions taken from another array**. The image above is exactly what I am trying to do.

**For each position** (or line if you want) **from "positions array"**, **check the "numbers array" for any repeated number that matches the first one**.

The above picture's example should return (print) something like:

- Repeated number: 3, count: 3, line: 0,0,0
- Repeated number: 3, count: 3, line: 0,1,2

And should ignore everything else.

Tried a thousand different loops but I failed.

Edit: A non-working example, below

```
print(finalValues)
for symbol in finalValues[0]:
    count = 0
    for line in lines:
        for i in range(0, len(line)):
            if finalValues[i][line[i]] == symbol:
                count += 1
        if count > 2:
            print("Repeated number: {}, count: {}, line: {}".format(symbol, count, line))
```

Edit: Example by numbers (taken from the picture above)

```
- We are looping through positions, and in the first loop we have positions: 1,1,1
- We should check numbers[0][1], numbers[1][1], numbers[2][1]
- In the next loop we have positions: 0,0,0
- We should check numbers[0][0], numbers[1][0], numbers[2][0]
- In the next loop we have positions: 2,2,2
- We should check numbers[0][2], numbers[1][2], numbers[2][2]
- In the next loop we have positions: 0,1,2
- We should check numbers[0][0], numbers[1][1], numbers[2][2]
```

Comment: @usr2564301 added a non working example, thanks

Comment: How is the mapping between **position array** to **numbers array** done?

Comment: @Anwarvic positions are pre-defined (hardcoded), and numbers are randomly generated in a loop. They are two different arrays, no mapping between them.

Comment: I tried running your code and got `NameError: name 'finalValues' is not defined`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Kevin , finalValues array is the green numbers array on the picture. Just named it differently.

Comment: @PM2Ring take 3 numeric positions from each inner-array of the left (red) array, and check those positions against the right (green) array to tell if the first position's number is repeated. And if yes, how many times.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, they are lists of lists. The picture has the exact ones marked as "examples".

Comment: @PM2Ring I bet you're the only one. My English are as bad as my Python skills.

Comment: @PM2Ring only if the first number is repeated, until a different number is found. 4,3,3 = 0reps. 4,3,4 = 0 reps, and 4,4,3 = 2reps of 4.

Comment: @PM2Ring but the second "board" is one-array-per-colum, not per-row. The left (red) is being read by rows, the right (green) is being read by columns. Example: numbers[0][0], numbers[0][1] and numbers[0][2] is the column of the picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215999/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-cdoc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to loop over the items in a `numbers` row and the corresponding `lines` row in parallel. The code below prints the values selected by each line in `lines` to make sure that we're getting the items that we actually want.

Once we have a selection, we use `head, *tail = selected` to put the 1st item into `head` and the remaining items into a list named `tail`, so that we can count the number of contiguous repetitions.

#### Code

```
lines = [
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
    [2,2,2],
    [0,1,2],
    [2,1,0],
]

def test(numbers):
    for row in lines:
        selected = [num[val] for num, val in zip(numbers, row)]
        print(row, '->', selected)
        head, *tail = selected
        count = 1
        for val in tail:
            if val == head:
                count += 1
            else:
                break
        if count > 2:
            print("Repeated number: {}, count: {}, line: {}".format(head, count, row))        

# Some test data
print("Testing...")
numbers = [[3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 5], [3, 7, 3]]
print('numbers', numbers)
test(numbers)    

print("Some more tests...")

# Some more test data
nums = [
    [[2, 2, 2], [4, 2, 2], [4, 2, 7]], 
    [[1, 3, 3], [5, 4, 3], [3, 4, 2]],
    [[7, 1, 6], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 5]], 
]

for numbers in nums:
    print('\nnumbers', numbers)
    test(numbers)
```

#### Output

```
Testing...
numbers [[3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 5], [3, 7, 3]]
[1, 1, 1] -> [4, 3, 7]
[0, 0, 0] -> [3, 3, 3]
Repeated number: 3, count: 3, line: [0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 2] -> [1, 5, 3]
[0, 1, 2] -> [3, 3, 3]
Repeated number: 3, count: 3, line: [0, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 0] -> [1, 3, 3]
Some more tests...

numbers [[2, 2, 2], [4, 2, 2], [4, 2, 7]]
[1, 1, 1] -> [2, 2, 2]
Repeated number: 2, count: 3, line: [1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0] -> [2, 4, 4]
[2, 2, 2] -> [2, 2, 7]
[0, 1, 2] -> [2, 2, 7]
[2, 1, 0] -> [2, 2, 4]

numbers [[1, 3, 3], [5, 4, 3], [3, 4, 2]]
[1, 1, 1] -> [3, 4, 4]
[0, 0, 0] -> [1, 5, 3]
[2, 2, 2] -> [3, 3, 2]
[0, 1, 2] -> [1, 4, 2]
[2, 1, 0] -> [3, 4, 3]

numbers [[7, 1, 6], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 5]]
[1, 1, 1] -> [1, 1, 1]
Repeated number: 1, count: 3, line: [1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0] -> [7, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2] -> [6, 1, 5]
[0, 1, 2] -> [7, 1, 5]
[2, 1, 0] -> [6, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!